# Stop execution of particular rspec test (not test suite) on first failure

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

Is there some programmatic way to force rspec test to stop on first failure?

For example,

1. I have a test suite with couple of rspec tests and I run them all at once.
2. Every rspec test is located in separate spec.rb file

If some failure occurs in any of these tests, I would like to stop the execution of that specific test further on that particular test step that failed but not to stop execution of whole test suite that I'm running.

I know there is a following way:

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.fail_fast = true
end
```

But defining it in any of the spec files that I ran in my test suite causes all execution of suite to fail.

Any way this case can be handled?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand exactly what you want, but do you mean if it's possible to stop all tests running in a particular file if a failure occurs while still continuing to run other tests in the suite?  If so, I'm not sure if that's possible.  If you mean is it possible to, say, run the whole test suite but display any failure messages immediately so you can investigate them while your other tests still continue to run, then try out the [Fuubar gem](https://github.com/jeffkreeftmeijer/fuubar).

Comment: So my idea is following:

1. I have 5 spec tests in my test suite  
2. Each of those tests is in separate spec file  
3. Each tests contains couple of contexts in which some verification is done.  
4. I run command rspec . to run complete test suite  
5. When something fails in one context inside one test (one file), I want to stop execution on that particular context and not to go further in that test, but to execute other spec files.  

Any chance this can be done?

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but I stumbled across it while looking to achieve this same behavior myself. After much fruitless searching, I came up with something that is fairly straightforward to implement which actually provides the desired behavior!

Just add the following to each spec file to skip subsequent examples (in that specific file) when an exception occurs:

```
  before :all do
    $continue = true
  end

  around :each do |example|
    if $continue
      $continue = false
      example.run
      $continue = true unless example.exception
    else
      example.skip
    end
  end
```

The logic here should be self-explanatory. Continue running examples until an exception occurs, then skip the rest of the examples for that spec. The around each hook facilitates this logic nicely since it can control the execution of each example. See the [RSpec documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec%2FCore%2FHooks%3Aaround) for more info on the "around" hook.