# With rspec+capybara, how to skip running tests if a 'header' smoke test fails?

Tags: ruby, rspec, nested

I want to run a smoke test "does the page exist with the form I want" before running the other tests in that spec.  If the above test fails there is not point running the other, form filling tests.

I thought I could structure as

```
describe
  it "smoke test" do
    // check form exists on page
  end
  describe "detailed form filling" do
    it "detailed" do
      detailed_stuff
    end
  end
end
```

and the inner describe would NOT run if the outer one failed but I am wrong, both run.

Is there a way to have a high level rspec test determine where or not to run the lower level detail ones below it ?
rspec *should* continue to run other test files, so `--fail-fast` does not seem to be suitable as that would seem to exit the whole suite

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop execution of particular rspec test (not test suite) on first failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085658/stop-execution-of-particular-rspec-test-not-test-suite-on-first-failure)

Comment: Note that you'll also need to either globally disable random spec ordering, or disable it for your specific file(s). See [here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/configuration/overriding-global-ordering) in the docs - you can set `order: :defined` for a specific context.

Comment: would the inner tests skip and show pending in the output or simply ignored all together?